# API Management - How to connect to a database to query tables

Tags: azure-api-management

I'm exploring different options and am looking to use API Management instead of standing up a Web API Service which I could do myself.

I would like to create a database that contains configuration data that gets hidden behind an API.

For example, if the following was defined:

```
SELECT CountryName, CityName
FROM tblCountry a
  INNER JOIN tblCountryCity b ON b.CountryID = a.CountryID
  INNER JOIN tblCity c ON c.CityID = b.CityID
WHERE a.CountryID = @countryID
```

I would like to call some endpoint

```
https://some_api_managment_service/CountryCity/1
```

with an associated ID to return the country name and corresponding cities.

Any information or documentation in how to connect the API Management to a database would be appreciated.

Comment: APIM is for managing APIs. Are you trying to not have to implement the API itself? If so, you should consider something else like [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview).

Comment: I think I just misunderstood what this is.  This is nothing more than a facade.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned you'll save a lot of time by using functions (or logic apps).

it is possible to query cosmos via policies. but it is not possible to query azure sql. which repository are you using?